# Reporting and Report designing tool in.net

Tags: html, .net, reporting

I have locations and from these location there are sensors used to monitor air parameters like CO2, CO, O3, PM10 etc so on. This data is every five minutes.

Now I need to create a tool where user will select the station from map or drop down list and time period and report type and get reports in charts, excel report or PDF. Similarly an administrator can design the reports that he will be able share with certain users and those users will be able to use that design in their reports so my question is **which reporting tool should I use?** Free or licensed.

1. Performance and end user experience (easy to use) should be excellent.
2. Will be using HTML5 and .net

Answer (score 0):

generally all peoples are used crystal Report tool to generate reports with .net, MS SQL server express edition supplies good reporting tool for free.

Answer (score 0):

If all this data it's stored in a database (which i assume it is, because you talk about historical data), you can use pretty much any reporting tool that can query a database; i recommend you to try several and pick the one that more closely fit your needs, for example, one tool that may fit your needs it's [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which can query almost any SQL database and offers a simple drag and drop interface, or you can even modify the query (if you want to) to improve it or optimize it.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.